# Getting access to cognito user attributes from within Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify-cli

I am using Cognito, API Gateway and Lambda functions in my architecture.

On the client I use AWS Amplify.API to make a request and the request is authorized by Cognito once it hits API Gateway. If the request is authorized, it is passed through to a Lambda function, where I need to have access to the logged-in user that is making the request in order to be able to run my business logic.

In the context of the Lambda function, I have access to some environment variables, `CognitoUserPoolId` being one of them.

I also have access to whatever of the request is passed through the API, lives in `event`.

```
{
  "tok": {
    "resource": "/some_resource",
    "path": "/some_resource",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,el;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,el-GR;q=0.4",
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "SE",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "Host": "XXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
      "origin": "http://localhost:8080",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8080/some_resource",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
      "Via": "2.0 XXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTelrg==",
      "x-amz-date": "20200527T233945Z",
      "x-amz-security-token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8fR",
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5XXXXa41-730XXXXXXXXXXabe42f1",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": {
      "Accept": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "Accept-Encoding": [
        "gzip, deflate, br"
      ],
      "Accept-Language": [
        "en-GB,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,el;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,el-GR;q=0.4"
      ],
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": [
        "https"
      ],
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": [
        "true"
      ],
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": [
        "false"
      ],
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": [
        "false"
      ],
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": [
        "false"
      ],
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": [
        "SE"
      ],
      "content-type": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "Host": [
        "XXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
      ],
      "origin": [
        "http://localhost:8080"
      ],
      "Referer": [
        "http://localhost:8080/some_resource"
      ],
      "sec-fetch-dest": [
        "empty"
      ],
      "sec-fetch-mode": [
        "cors"
      ],
      "sec-fetch-site": [
        "cross-site"
      ],
      "User-Agent": [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
      ],
      "Via": [
        "2.0 XXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
      ],
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": [
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTelrg=="
      ],
      "x-amz-date": [
        "20200527T233945Z"
      ],
      "x-amz-security-token": [
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8fR"
      ],
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
        "Root=1-5XXXXa41-730XXXXXXXXXXabe42f1"
      ],
      "X-Forwarded-For": [
        "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
      ],
      "X-Forwarded-Port": [
        "443"
      ],
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
        "https"
      ]
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": null,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
      "resourceId": "5qXXXXXXX",
      "resourcePath": "/some_resource",
      "httpMethod": "GET",
      "extendedRequestId": "NNwKXXXXXXXXX=",
      "requestTime": "27/May/2020:23:39:45 +0000",
      "path": "/dev/some_resource",
      "accountId": "18XXXXXXXX",
      "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
      "stage": "dev",
      "domainPrefix": "XXXXXX",
      "requestTimeEpoch": 1590622785474,
      "requestId": "XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "eu-central-1:XXXXXX-YYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYY",
        "accountId": "181606720624",
        "cognitoIdentityId": "eu-central-1:XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
        "caller": "SOME_STRING_HERE:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
        "sourceIp": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
        "principalOrgId": null,
        "accessKey": "ACCESS_KEY_HERE",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": "authenticated",
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": "cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_XXXXXX,cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_XXXXXX:CognitoSignIn:XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
        "userArn": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXX:assumed-role/amplify-XXXXXX-dev-XXXXXX-authRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
        "user": "SOME_STRING_HERE:CognitoIdentityCredentials"
      },
      "domainName": "XXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
      "apiId": "XXXXXX"
    },
    "body": null,
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
}
```

With all this info at hand, how can I access the user attributes of the user that made the request?

I have been looking into:
[Boto3 CognitoIdentityProvider.get_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.get_user)
and
[Boto3 CognitoIdentityProvider.admin_get_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_get_user), however both require either the `AccessToken` or `userId` and neither is available in the context of the Lambda function. The only way I've figured is to pass some extra info in the payload of the request, but this does not seem like the best way to retrieve the user attributes really.

**EDIT**

I am not using a custom authorizer on the API. When setting up the API with Amplify, I chose to have protected paths and all requests are authenticaetd/authorized against a Cognito User Pool. After `amplify push` I can see that the deployed API has `AWS_IAM` under `Auth` in Method Request for all resources.

`Amplify.API.get` when making a request includes headers for authorisation, more specifically:

```
:authority: XXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
:method: GET
:path: /dev/some_resource
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,el;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,el-GR;q=0.4
authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAXXXXXXXX/20200528/eu-central-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=b6a7aXXX1c447bXXX...XXX
content-type: application/json
origin: http://localhost:8080
referer: http://localhost:8080/dashboard
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
x-amz-date: 20200528T075958Z
x-amz-security-token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...XXXXXXXXXX
```

The API resource is integrated to a Lambda function, with Lambda Proxy Integration. I can see that the Lambda function is being called, therefore the request is authorised alright. However, all I have in the `event` in Lambda is what I have pasted in the first clip above.

Given that this is a proxy integration, I would expect that all that is in context at the API should be forwarded to the Lambda behind the API. However, I cannot see how to access user_attributes with any of the info that I have available in Lambda. Any pointers?

**EDIT 2**

I am now looking into passing user-related data from the client with the use of custom headers, perhaps something like:

```
'x-user-sub': '58ce94f6-53vd-4s3e-b088-cd6f85s0ff43'
```

and then use the below in my Lambda function to get the user attributes:

```
  c_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
  response = c_client.admin_get_user(
    UserPoolId='eu-central-1_XXXXXX',
    Username='58ce94f6-53vd-4s3e-b088-cd6f85s0ff43'
  )
```

The above returns:

```
{
  'Username': '58ce94f6-53vd-4s3e-b088-cd6f85s0ff43',
  'UserAttributes': [
    {
      'Name': 'sub',
      'Value': '58ce94f6-53vd-4s3e-b088-cd6f85s0ff43'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'email_verified',
      'Value': 'true'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'phone_number_verified',
      'Value': 'true'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'phone_number',
      'Value': '+46XXXXXXXXXX'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'email',
      'Value': 'XXXXXX.XXXXX@YYYY.com'
    }
  ],
  'UserCreateDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 15, 43, 3, 370000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
  'UserLastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 16, 32, 43, 424000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
  'Enabled': true,
  'UserStatus': 'CONFIRMED',
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': 'e441edd4-XXX-46ba-XXX-922691471f2c',
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'date': 'Thu, 28 May 2020 12:58:18 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
      'content-length': '431',
      'connection': 'keep-alive',
      'x-amzn-requestid': 'e441edd4-XXX-46ba-XXX-922691471f2c'
    },
    'RetryAttempts': 0
  }
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing with this solution? Am I introducing any security risks by passing the `sub` in the customer header?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: In your mapping template $context.authorizer.claims.sub == userId

Comment: @pkarfs Thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting that I forward this through to the Lambda from API Gateway? If so, any chance you could provide a pointer how to do this? Some link perhaps? Finally, is ```userId``` the username of the cognito user or how can I use the value of that variable?

Comment: No worries, firstly your event requestContext doesn't have a authorizer.claims key object, which i would suggest means you don't actually have authorizer enabled/required (or forgot to deploy your rest api). You can either forward the value through to your lambda if your using a Lambda as a proxy, or through the integration mapping template if your using lambda as a service. Lastly sub is the unique value assigned to your user in cognito.  If username isnt specified then yes sub = username.

Comment: Thanks pkarfs. I am using a AWS_IAM authorisation, not a custom authorizer, not sure if that relates to why there is no authorizer object in requestContext. I've added more info to describe the flow. Also, I am using a Lambda proxy integration between the API and the Lambda function behind it, does that not mean the API shoudl automatically forward all info related to the request to the Lambda function?

Comment: You should not be passing sub in the header, the whole point of token authorisation is to avoid the need for that. Also if your using cognito why are you using AWS_IAM authorisation? change it to your cognito userpool.  This is the reason your not getting user context responses.

Comment: Thanks pkarfs, Just to get this clear, isn't the regular flow to pass the token in the "Authorization" header? The sub is included in there, unless I'm missing something obvious here, not impossible :)

Comment: @pkarfs AWS_IAM was set in place by Amplify when using their CLI to deploy the whole set up with Cognito, API and Lambda functions for backend. Then you can also use Amplify.API module (which utilises axios in its core) to consume the API and it sets everything up so as to use the Auth logic that has been put in place etc. In short, the API and the API resources were created and set up by the amplify CLI as per the instructions to use Cognito for Auth, the Amplify CLI automates the access control policies for all the involved AWS resources.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/) might help you.

Especially, this part:

> API Gateway’s Authorizer for Cognito User Pools
>
> API Gateway has recently launched support for Cognito User Pool
>   Authorizer. If you use Cognito User Pool Authorizer, you do not need
>   to set up your own custom authorizer to validate tokens. Once your API
>   methods are configured with Cognito User Pool Authorizer, you can pass
>   unexpired ID Token in the Authorization header to your API methods. If
>   it’s a valid ID Token for a user of your User Pool, you can then
>   access all the claims of ID Token in your API using
>   ‘$context.authorizer.claims’.
>
> For example
>   ‘$context.authorizer.claims.email’ will return user’s email address
>   and ‘$context.authorizer.claims.sub’ will return you user’s unique
>   identifier. If the ID token is expired or is invalid, Cognito User
>   Pool Authorizer will send Unauthorized (401) response to the caller.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html) there are some examples on how to override apigateway request/response parameters

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) you can see how to setup integration and what data is passed to the API Gateway.

Worth to check the references for [data mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) and [access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not very confident on whether I am using a Cognito User Pool authoriser. I have deployed the API using amplify/cli and when I look on the AWS API Gateway console I see "AWS_IAM" under "Authorization" in the Method Request. Perhaps this is a newer authorization flow?? At the same time, I have a Lambda proxy integration, should not all request data be included in the ```event```? Is it not possible to use any of the attributes that are available to me in ```event``` to retrieve the Cognito user for the given session?